# Sass @extend behavior like LESS and @import

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I have just migrated from `LESS` to `SASS/SCSS`, because of most advice I've found on the net and new version of bootstrap.
But I am really missing one important feature of `LESS` that every class style can be treated as an `mixin`.

```
.social-icons__list {
  .list-inline;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use `@include` for simple class, it should be annotated with `@mixin`. And in case of `placeholder`I need also to annotate class with `%`.

But like in my case, I need to extend existing class and get behavior like using placeholder.

In case of `SASS` it generates following `CSS`

```
.list-inline, .social-icons__list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -5px; }
```

But I need to copy styles only

```
 .social-icons__list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -5px; }
```

I would accept it, but I also had to download `bootstrap sass` sources and `@import "../external-dependency/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

And this line of code makes compiler to copy all styles from `bootstrap sources` into my compiled file.

So maybe there are solutions to these problems.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Sass doesn't have class-as-mixin feature like Less. You only real option is `@extend` though, it's worth nothing the differences in how this behaves, that it hoists the class name to the class that you are @extend-ing.

The bootstrap issue is a separate one, as if you wanted to use BS classes as less mixins you would still need them in your compiled file. The best strategy for that is use the official [bootstrap sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) only import the parts you are using. There are also @mixins defined for most styles/components so you can just import the mixins files and use those if you don't want any actual classes.

Comment: Thx for answer, is there any way I can use bootstrap import ( As you may see I have already used bootstrap sass) as dependency only, to include only parts used in my `scss` files ?

Comment: There isn't a way to only pull the classes you are using. You can import only the sections of bootstrap you are using. ie `@import "../external-dependency/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/grid";` or just use the mixins to build your own classes `@import "../external-dependency/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/grid";` or you could look at using something like uncss to strip the unused classes at build time https://github.com/giakki/uncss